# Unittesting function in Python that has try/except statament

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, try-except

My class has a method called updateTag that executes a command against AWS endpoint.
I created a unit test for it and I mocked the AWS call, but I don't know how to test the except block.

When I execute the updateTag, if DryRun is False it should return 0 and for True it should return 1

Could you help me?

Here is my function:

```
def updateTag(self, resourceInterface: boto3.resource, commandExpression: str):
    response = {'command': commandExpression,
                'returnCode': bool, 'error': []}
    try:
        eval('resourceInterface.' + commandExpression)
        response['returnCode'] = 0
    except Exception as e:
        response['returnCode'] = 1
        response['error'] = e.args

    return response
```

and here is my unit test code:

```
    def test_updateTag_with_string_command_and_dryrun_set_false_should_pass(self):
        commandsExpression = "Image('ami-0b1116af7f69faeab').create_tags(DryRun=False,Tags=[{'Key':'state', 'Value': 'expired'}, {'Key': 'timestamp', 'Value':'expired#2019-11-13T22:46:32.725Z'}])"
        boto3 = MagicMock()
        ec2Resource = boto3.resource('ec2')
        imageLifecycle = Lifecycle(self.lifeCycleRules, self.dryRunEnabled)
        response = imageLifecycle.updateTag(ec2Resource, commandsExpression)
        self.assertEqual(response['returnCode'],0)

    def test_updateTag_with_string_command_and_dryrun_set_true_should_pass(self):
        commandsExpression = "Image('ami-00000000000000000').create_tags(DryRun=True,Tags=[{'Key':'state', 'Value': 'expired'}, {'Key': 'timestamp', 'Value':'expired#2019-11-13T22:46:32.725Z'}])"
        boto3 = MagicMock()
        ec2Resource = boto3.resource('ec2')
        imageLifecycle = Lifecycle(self.lifeCycleRules, self.dryRunEnabled)
        response = imageLifecycle.updateTag(ec2Resource, commandsExpression)
        self.assertEqual(response['returnCode'],1)
```

Thank you.

Comment: I am looking into it. From first sight: boto3.resource i.e. ur ec2Resource should raise an explicit exception which will make ur program fall for an exception. I don't see that right now. Looking into it :)

Comment: Just try changing ec2Resource = "fake_source_error_should_occur"

This will tear down the updateTag function and you should land into the exception block.